# apply method didn't work as expected when DataFrame is empy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I've searched relevant posts before I create this post, but I didn't get what I want.

This is a simplified example shows that I use the apply method to create a new DataFrame named df_new based on the old one named df. The new DataFrame has different columns compared with the old one.

```
import pandas

def func(row): 
    return pandas.Series({'d': row['a'], 'e': row['b'] + row['c']})

df = pandas.DataFrame({  
    'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],  
    'b': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],  
    'c': [50, 60, 70, 80, 90]  
})  

df_new = df.apply(func, axis=1)   
df_new = df_new.reset_index(drop=True)  
  
print(df_new)
```

The result is work as I expected when the df isn't empty.

```
   d    e
0  1   60
1  2   80
2  3  100
3  4  120
4  5  140
```

But if I take an empty dataset instead, the apply method didn't work as I expected, it just return
an empty DataFrame with columns like ['a','b','c'] , not with columns like ['d','e'].

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(columns = ['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

```
Empty DataFrame   
Columns: [a, b, c]
Index: []
```

I wonder why apply method didn't work as I expected. If I can solve this problem with adding some arguments when using apply method.

Comment: what is your expectation from an empty df, should it just not run the function ?

Comment: `apply` sends `row` to your `func` but you don't have rows in empty `DataFrame` so `apply` has nothing to do. And it can't create columns `d`, `e`

Answer (score 3):

##### TL;DR

This is the expected behavior. You should use `df.apply(func, axis=1).reindex(columns=['d', 'e'])`.

---

##### detailed answer

When you run `apply`, this is handled internally by [`pandas.core.apply.frame_apply`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v2.1.3/pandas/core/frame.py#L10022-L10034) which creates an intermediate object  (`op`):

```
        from pandas.core.apply import frame_apply

        op = frame_apply(
            self,
            func=func,
            axis=axis,
            raw=raw,
            result_type=result_type,
            by_row=by_row,
            args=args,
            kwargs=kwargs,
        )
        return op.apply().__finalize__(self, method="apply")
```

In the [`op.apply()`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v2.1.3/pandas/core/apply.py#L810-L812) step, there is a check to see if one of the axes is empty:

```
        # all empty
        if len(self.columns) == 0 and len(self.index) == 0:
            return self.apply_empty_result()
```

Which redirects to [`apply_empty_result`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v2.1.3/pandas/core/apply.py#L862-L906), runs the function on an empty Series, checks if the function should aggregate/reduce (in such cast this produces a Series as output), **if not this returns a copy of the original object**:

```
        if should_reduce:
            # ...
        else:
            return self.obj.copy()
```

Which is your case.

To avoid that, you have to use [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
out = df.apply(func, axis=1).reindex(columns=['d', 'e'])
```

Output:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [d, e]
Index: []
```

Comment: Your answer makes it more understandable and inspired me a lot.
```
        # all empty
        if len(self.columns) == 0 and len(self.index) == 0:
            return self.apply_empty_result()
```
I've noticed here before. I put some debug snippets here, but it didn't trigged, so I didn't see them further.
I've tried that again. It goes here:
```
        # one axis empty
        elif not all(self.obj.shape):
            return self.apply_empty_result()
```
and then return the columns as same as the original dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

`apply` sends `row` to `func` but you don't have rows in empty `DataFrame`.
So `apply` has nothing to send to `func` and it doesn't run `func`.
So `func` can't create columns `d`, `e`.
And you can't add parameter to `apply` to change it.

You should rather change all code and do

```
df_new = pandas.DataFrame()
df_new["d"] = df["a"]
df_new["e"] = df["b"] + df["c"]
```

Comment: "*it doesn't run func*" -> it's not true, if you had a `print` in the function it should display once and internally create an Series of NaNs

Comment: @mozway good point. I didn't check it with `print()`